# Custom alert for ReplayKit screen capture

Tags: ios, swift, alert, screen-capture, replaykit

My App uses ReplayKit for screen recording. It shows the below permission alert when RPScreenRecorder.shared().startCapture() is called. Is it possible to change the text content in the alert?

> Allow screen capture in <App_Name>?
> This application will capture your screen and you will not have a chance to review it.

Comment: Any solutions maybe?